# Standardized format for a non-specific time interval

Tags: localization, internationalization, datetime-format, iso8601

I'm currently localizing a website, and part of the information presented is the length of an audio file.  Let's say the length of the file is `06:47:58` (6 hours, 47 minutes, 58 seconds).

Is there a standard to localize non-specific time intervals to, like dates?  I see ISO-8601 has a [date-specific time interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals) (aka between date A time 1 to date B time 2), but nothing about general time.

Thank you for the help